# How to download zip(folder zip) from S3 bucket store the files in it to different S3 bucket, using spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3, unzip

I have a requirement where the input to my module is a zip file(i.e., a folder of files zipped) and placed to S3 bucket. I have to unzip from S3 and store the files in it to a different S3 bucket. Can any one help me how to achieve this using spring boot ?

Comment: have u tried something... if yes then share your code in question

Comment: Basic flow :: Download the file from s3 -> Unzip fiiles > iterate the files > and upload to the another bucket of s3.

How to unzip the file in java take a ref > https://www.journaldev.com/960/java-unzip-file-example